# How to create an APK but no run it

Tags: android, linux, virtual-machine, kivy

So I want to compile a kivy project so I had a go at following [this guide.](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html)

I created a VM as I only have windows machines and was wondering if there is a version of this line that just creates the apk as opposed to trying to push it to a device:

```
buildozer android debug deploy run
```

Thanks, Ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type `buildozer android debug`.